# sqlite: multiple where clause syntax: where s="somestring" and where i=0;

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

What mistake am I making?

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table t (s text not null, i integer);
sqlite> select * from t where s="somestring"; /* works */;
sqlite> select * from t where i=0; /* works */;
sqlite> select * from t where s="somestring" and where i=0;
Error: near "where": syntax error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify where 2 times in this query

```
sqlite> select * from t where s="somestring" and i=0;
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select * 
from t 
where s="somestring" 
and i=0;
```

instead of

```
select * 
from t 
where s="somestring" 
and where i=0;
```

Comment: What does your answer add to the previously accepted answer?

Comment: I posted this answer before that one, and I guess this one does not add anything to the accepted answer. So should I remove this one?

Comment: @mustaccio The accepted answer was actually the last of the 3 posted.

Answer (score 1):

`select * from t where s="somestring" and i=0;`

Remove the last `where` - you only need and can only have one `where` per statement.